# EaselJS library version issue

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

I am writing a simple interactive animation for a website and am having an issue with the easeljs library.

The first part of my code has a spritesheet animation that I grabbed the sample code from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davrous/2012/03/16/html5-gaming-animating-sprites-in-canvas-with-easeljs/ and modified it accordingly.

The second part of my code has some interactivity (user click on some images and they produce sounds).

OK, if I use the library **easeljs-0.6.0.min** the animation will work but the code will raise an error saying that "object.on is not a function" (on click event that I use for the interactivity). This code causes it:

```
function ConfigureIcon(object)
{
    object.on("click", function(evt){
    }
}
```

Then if I try to use instead the library **easeljs-0.8.0.min** the interactivity will work but then the code will raise an error saying that "createjs.BitmapAnimation is not a constructor". This code causes it:

```
bmpEyesAnimation = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(EyesSpriteSheet);
```

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EaselJS 0.8.x, the [`BitmapAnimation`](http://docs.createjs.jp/EaselJS_docs-0.6.0/classes/BitmapAnimation.html) type has been renamed to [`Sprite`](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Sprite.html).

According to the release notes, [this was done in version 0.7](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/blob/master/VERSIONS.txt#L163). The release notes give no other instructions about how to transition from `BitmapAnimation` to `Sprite`, which suggests you can simply rename it and it will work as-is.

Comment: Thank you very much **apsillers**!  It solved my issue. I had also to update my code for the tick event. :-)